# Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

I keep getting the error: "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Team" on my constructor for this class:

```
package ncaa.Data
{       
    import ncaa.Data.Team;

    public class PositionedTeams{

        public var Position:int;
        public var TopTeam:Team;
        public var BottomTeam:Team;

        public function Team(pos:int, topTeam:Team, bottomTeam:Team){
            Position = pos;
            TopTeam = topTeam;
            BottomTeam = bottomTeam;
        }
    }
}
```

The class, Team is imported on the third line, what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a name conflict. The constructor you have is `Team` not `PositionedTeams`.